# Why we need to compile the program of progress 4GL?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I would like to know Why we need to compile the program of progress 4GL? Really what is happening behind there? Why we are getting .r file after compiled the program? When we check the syntax if its correct then we will get one message box 'Syntax is correct' how its finding the errors and showing the messages.Any explanations welcome and appreciated.

Comment: You really shouldn't tag your questions with plain old "progress".  That is going to get them lumped in with everyone posting about "progress indicators" and since most of those people have never heard of OpenEdge or Progress (the company) and have no idea what the progress 4lg/abl are you will tend to attract an awful lot of downvotes out of sheer ignorance.

Answer (score 6):

Benefits of compiled r-code include:

1. Syntax checking
2. Faster execution (r-code executes faster)
3. Security (r-code is not "human readable" and tampering with it will likely be noticed)
4. Licensing (r-code runtime licenses are much less expensive)

For "how its finding the errors and showing the messages" -- at a high level it is like any compiler.  It evaluates the provided source against a syntax tree and lets you know when you violate the rules.  Compiler design and construction is a fairly advanced topic that probably isn't going to fit into a simple SO question -- but if you had something more specific that could stand on its own as a question someone might be able to help.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that when you compile, you're translating your program to a language the machine understands. You're asking two different questions here, so let me give you a simple answer to the first: you don't NEED to compile if you're the only one using the program, for example. But in order to have your program optimized (since it's already at the machine language level) and guarantee no one is messing with your logic, we compile the code and usually don't allow regular users to access the source code.

The second question, how does the syntax checker work, I believe it would be better for you to Google and choose some articles to read about compilers. They're complex, but in a nutshell what they do is take what Progress expects as full, operational commands, and compare to what you do. For example, if you do a

```
Find first customer where customer.active = yes no-error.
```

Progress will check if customer is a table, if customer.active is a field in that table, if it's the logical type, since you are filtering if it is yes, and if your whole conditions can be translated to one single true or false Boolean value. It goes on to check if you specified a lock (and default to shared if you haven't, like in my example, which is a no-no, by the way), what happens if there are multiple records (since I said first, then get just the first one) and finally what happens if it fails. If you check the find statement, there are more options to customize it, and the compiler will simply compare your use of the statement to what Progress can have for it. And collect all errors if it can't. That's why sometimes compilers will give you generic messages. Since they don't know what you're trying to do, all they can do is tell you what's basically wrong with what you wrote.

Hope this helps you understand.